# getting error in asp.net after uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, security-policy

Kindly check the [link](http://www.gsm-partners.com.vital-ns.co.uk/new_gsm/public/home.aspx)

I've uploaded the website and after uploading when I run the application it starts giving me this error:

> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like what ever that page is trying to do, your server wont allow it. Are you in a medium trust hosting environment?

Comment: didn't know the hosting environment trust?can you tell me how to check this trust?

Comment: Yep - definitely sounds like hosting problem.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following solution [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320268) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1092369/1649206.aspx) and see if it helps.